# Install JAVA 8 in home directory Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, java-8, environment-variables

I have downloaded tar.gz file and unzipped it. I don't have admin access, so I added PATH variable: export PATH=$PATH:/home/shashank/jdk1.8.0_144/bin in .bashrc and reloaded by source ~/.bashrc. But when I do "java -version". I cant see any update.

Comment: There might be a different Java version in the path before your own directory. Put your own directory first: `export PATH=/home/shashank/jdk1.8.0_144/bin:$PATH`

Comment: Also look if JAVA_HOME is set. Change it accordingly. Some Java applications use it in their startup scripts.

Comment: @aschoerk I have tried that -bash: /home/shashank/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/java: File o directory non esistente
was the error

Comment: Did you download and unpack "Linux x64" ( Java SE Development Kit 8u144) the file was jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz? I did that just now and it worked. If not, what is your ubuntu version? call "lsb_release -a" what does it deliver?

Comment: @aschoerk  My file name is jdk-8u144-linux-i586.tar.gz. Output is :No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description: Debian GNU/Linux 8.9 (jessie)
Release: 8.9
Codename: jessie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that 64bit machine is not supporting 32 bit Java Compiler.
It got fixed when x64 version jdk is installed.